# Custom post type Wordpress query by category

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, categories, custom-taxonomy

I have the following query which outputs a list of categories for my custom post type called STORIES.

```
<?php
$taxonomy = 'story-category';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<div class="category-grid-box">
<div class="category-grid-content">' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a> </div>
</div>  ';
}
?>
```

This outputs a list of links for my categories and works great.

My problem is, I don't know how to write the query on the next page which will list all the posts in that chosen category.

So my query lists the categories...
- Apples
- Oranges
- Bananas

If you click on Apples and go to that page, what query do I use to list all of the STORIES that have the category APPLES?

Any ideas? Can't get any solution to work.

I have the following query, but it lists ALL of the categories and ALL of the posts within them. How can I modify it to just show the posts for the page I am on?

```
<?php
$custom_terms = get_terms('story-category');
foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
wp_reset_query();
$args = array('post_type' => 'stories',
'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'story-category',
'field' => 'slug',
'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
),
),
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if($loop->have_posts()) {
echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
echo '<p><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
endwhile;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create custom taxonomy template for custom post : [LINK](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/taxonomy-archives-list-posts-by-post-type--cms-20340)

Comment: This outputs ALL categories and their posts. I just want to list the ones for the page I am on. If I am on the APPLES page - i only want to list the APPLES posts. not EVERY post form every category like attached link.

Comment: have you create template or custom taxonomy template..?

Comment: as per your taxonomy what is your file name?

Comment: have you add 'has_archive=>true' in creation of custom post type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80736/discussion-between-vrajesh-and-lowercase).

Comment: Feels like blog spam, here's a [simple guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png) to the Wordpress theme hierarchy

Answer (score 2):

Hope this help:

```
 $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
           'taxonomy' => 'story-category',
           'field'    => 'slug',
           'terms'    => $term->slug,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

[Class Reference/WP Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: That would work if the page you are on is 'bob'.
How do I list all of the posts within the category I am already in? So I don't have to rewrite the query for 100's of pages?

Comment: just added a new query which might help.

Comment: When you click on apple it will take to the apple taxonomy. page. Create a separate taxonomy template( taxonomy.php ) and put the code in that. That will surely work there!

Comment: this code is already going in taxonomy.php but geting blank results with your code.

Comment: Can you echo me the category title in your code? It is showing blank as nothing is being output?

Comment: try this $t = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), 'story-category'); echo $t->name;